# 2 conditions vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements

I am trying to make a summary sheet of matches played and won from a daily data sheet.

I have now a working code ; I have redesigned the sheet slightly. As vlookup and xlookup were giving me syntax errors, I have used match function. I have put the daily data from column A onwards in this sheet itself.

```
Sub won()
    Dim rw As Long, rc As Long, rr As Long, r As Long, C As Long, lr2 As Long
    Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range, sh As Worksheet
    
    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet4")
    lr2 = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row 'rows of input data
    
    Columns("A:C").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "A2:A" & lr2), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "B2:B" & lr2), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:C" & lr2)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Set rng = Range("B2:B" & lr2) 'Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set rng2 = Range("A2:A" & lr2) 'Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    With sh
        lastcol = Unique(rng) ' to know number of columns appearing in report
        TickerCount = Unique(rng2) ' to know the number of Tickers
        rr = Application.Match("Name", .Columns(1), 0)
        rc = .Cells(rr, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 2
        .Cells(rr, rc + 1) = .Cells(rr + 1, 2).Value2
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        For rw = rr + 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, .Columns(rc), 0)) Then
                .Cells(Rows.Count, rc).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = .Cells(rw, 1).Value2
            End If
            If IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(rw, 2).Value2, .Cells(rr, rc).Resize(1, (lastcol + 10)), 0)) Then
                .Cells(rr, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1) = .Cells(rw, 2).Value2
            End If

            r = Application.Match(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, .Columns(rc), 0)
            C = Application.Match(.Cells(rw, 2).Value2, .Rows(rr), 0)
            .Cells(r, C) = .Cells(rw, 3).Value ' & "_" & .Cells(rw, 2).Value
        Next rw

        

    End With
    Dim startColumn As Integer

    Dim endColumn As Integer

    startColumn = 6

    endColumn = (startColumn + lastcol) - 1
    Range(Columns(startColumn), Columns(endColumn)).Select
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(1, endColumn)) _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
   
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Sort
        .SetRange Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(lr2, endColumn))
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub

Function Unique(ListRange As Range) As Integer

Dim CellValue As Variant

Dim UniqueValues As New Collection

Application.Volatile

On Error Resume Next

For Each CellValue In ListRange

UniqueValues.Add CellValue, CStr(CellValue) ' add the unique item

Next

Unique = UniqueValues.Count

End Function
```

The code might not be elegant but solves the task.

Thanks,

[image: screenshot]

Comment: *Kindly help me in starting with the vba code* read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: By 'starting the code' I had meant the logic and flow. Not posting any code doesn't mean that no effort has been made.

Answer (score 2):

you have many ways to do this
The first way to create a "Ref" column and sum the "Name + Date" then use that column ref in Vlookup normally

**Ref Column:** `=K2&L2`
**The Equestion will be :-** `=VLOOKUP(($A2&B$1),$J:$N,5,0)`

[image]

[image]

The second way is, if you have office 365, then you can use XLOOKUP function directly without creating the ref column and it will be like below

**Equation:-** `=XLOOKUP(($A9&B$8),($K:$K&$L:$L),$N:$N)`

[image]

The final way is to create a pivot table:-

[image]

Comment: @Badr, Vlookup with ref column and xlookup won't help much; too much manual work involved. I will definitely see the pivot solution and report. VBA is what I need.